# SwiftUI custom animation does not apply on inner view change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a custom bounce animation applied to a view with multiple inner views which can change depending on conditions. My issue is that when the inner view changes, the animation applied to a parent no longer applies to it.

Example:

[image]

Sample Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var number = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                if number == 1 {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                }
                else if number == 2 {
                    ProgressView()
                }
                else {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
            .bounceEffect()
            Button {
                if number != 3 {
                    number += 1
                }
                else {
                    number = 1
                }
            } label: {
                Text("CHANGE")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct BounceEffect: ViewModifier {
    
    @State var bounce = false
    
    var allow: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .offset(y: (bounce && allow) ? -5 : 0)
            .animation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 1, stiffness: 350, damping: 5, initialVelocity: 10).repeatForever(autoreverses: false).delay(1), value: UUID())
            .onAppear {
                if allow {
                    bounce.toggle()
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func bounceEffect(allow: Bool = true) -> some View {
        modifier(BounceEffect(allow: allow))
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the bounceEffect don't get the button after you change because you are creating the new image when ever you tap the button `change`.

The action you need here: just only change the system image of the image not creating new one every time the button `change` is tapped

The code will be like this

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var number = 1
    @State var imageName = "person"

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    Image(systemName: imageName)
                }
                .bounceEffect()
                Button {
                    if number != 3 {
                        number += 1
                    }
                    else {
                        number = 1
                    }

                    if number == 1 {
                        imageName = "person"
                    }
                    else if number == 2 {
                        imageName = "globe"
                    }
                    else {
                        imageName = "square"
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("CHANGE")
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .padding()
        }
}
```

The result
[image: The result]

Comment: This is much more scalable than my answer.

Comment: @bewithyou This will not work if the views are of different kind. I used images just as an example. I updated the question with a more accurate example of the problem.

Comment: Dear @Astro, as your previous it just has 3 buttons in same type. That's the reason of this solution. Like your update, you should use .opacity like vacawama's answer

Answer (score 1):

When the new images appear, they aren’t the ones involved in the animation. One way to fix this is to include all 3 images from the start, and just cycle their visibility by changing `opacity`:

```
ZStack {
    Circle()
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        
    Image(systemName: "person")
        .opacity(number == 1 ? 1 : 0)

    Image(systemName: "globe")
        .opacity(number == 2 ? 1 : 0)

    Image(systemName: "square")
        .opacity(number == 3 ? 1 : 0)
}
```

---

[@bewithyou’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73629661/1630618) is more scalable and should be the accepted answer.  Here is a better way to structure the selection of your images:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var number = 0
    let names = ["person", "globe", "square", "house", "car"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                Image(systemName: names[number])
            }
            .bounceEffect()
            Button {
                number = (number + 1) % names.count
            } label: {
                Text("CHANGE")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```